# How can I recover deleted records from a table in oracle sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, delete-row, recover

I have a cursor which deletes records from a table which are more than or equal to 1 year old. It keeps past one year data and deletes records whose creation_date (column_name) is greater than one year. The cursor is running for the past 3 years. I now have to recover deleted records.

I tried something like this
`select * from <table> as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' hour;`

But it shows data for a particular instance of time in the past. I want all the records which were deleted from the table by the cursor. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: I would suggest providing example/sample data to provide further clarity to your question.

Comment: BTW, the safest thing is to 1) move the data to a new table, 2) save that table to archival storage like compressed CSV, 3) delete using that table or the values in archival storage and 4) drop that new table.  Sometimes there is no undo for delete.  If you back it up first, they you can undo if it turns out to have gone awry.  Disk is cheap!  No rush, you have a year!

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
select * from <table> as of systimestamp - interval '1' hour
minus
select * from <table>;
```

that should show you any records that existed an hour ago but don't exist now. If that shows you what you want, then use that to feed an insert as select statement to recover the missing records.